Приставки "не" и "недо" - как их различать?
Как правильно написать фразы?

Почему вы не( )доделали макет, который я оплатил?
Отец не( )договорил свой тост.

Вроде бы и там, и там можно увидеть и отрицание, и неполноту.

Этот вопрос похож на: Какова разница между приставкой недо и частицей не с глаголом?. Если вы уверены что это не так, нажмите [edit], дайте ясно понять, чем ваш вопрос отличается от дубликата и/или почему ответы на него не помога

Это не дубликат, так как вопрос для каждого конкретного случая решается в индивидуальном порядке, а в ссылке приведена тема с самыми общими рассуждениями.  //  С другой стороны, нужен контекст, из которого была бы понятной ситуация, а этого в вопросе нет. Не имеет смысла решать такие задачи  отвлеченно и абстрактно.
